# unable to connect oracle 19c to sqldeveloper 21.2 "Status : Failure -Test failed: null"

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to connect my oracle database version 19c on sqldeveloper version 21.2.0 but for some reason when I create a new connection using a user that I've created using `CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY password` and click 'test' or 'connect' I get the error `Status : Failure -Test failed: null`. I have no direction on what to do as I'm quite new to SQL though I've tried granting the user(s) created privileges for `create session` and `connect` though here I get another error claiming `user or role 'oracle_usera' does not exist`. I apologize if the mistake is obvious and I will appreciate any contribution made.

Comment: Any chance you could add a screenshot showing the connection details you are attempting?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't coz I didn't take any though I've resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the current installation for Sqldeveloper and installed a later version and this solved my problem.